# uploading docx, zip, rar, pdf, ppt, in php

Tags: php, input, types

I am trying to make file uploading page where docx, zip, rar, pdf, ppt these extensions only allowed to upload here I wrote code about it but its showing invalid file type error
help to solve it

```
$allowed_types = array('zip','rar','docx','ppt');
$tmp = explode(".", $_FILES['file']['name']);
$ext = end($tmp);
$upload_dir ="uploads/assignments/";
if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] !=""){
if( ($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/zip")
|| ($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/rar")
|| ($_FILES['file']['type']=="'application/docx'")
|| ($_FILES['file']['type']=="application/ppt")
&& ($_FILES['file']['size']<400000)
&& in_array($ext,$allowed_types))
```

Comment: please show us the full error

Comment: Try grouping all of your OR conditions in one set of brackets, so that only one result is evaluated from them..

Comment: it's showing invalid file selected

Comment: remove single quotes from "'application/docx'" and try again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$allowed =  array('zip','rar','docx','ppt');//allowed types
$filename = $_FILES['file']['name'];//file name

$ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);//extension checking

if(!in_array($ext,$allowed) )
{
    echo 'Not Valid';
}
else
{
    echo ' Valid'
}
```

Comment: @ImranIqbal Enjoy Codding :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this code :

```
 $allowedExts = array('zip','rar','docx','ppt');
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $upload_dir ="uploads/assignments/";
    if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['name'] !=""){
    if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/zip")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/rar")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/docx")
      || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "application/ppt"))
      && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 400000)
      && in_array ($extension, $allowedExts))
```

Answer (score 0):

USE:

```
.xls
application/vnd.ms-excel

.xlsx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet

.ppt
application/vnd.ms-powerpoint
.pptx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation

.docx
application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document

.pdf 
application/pdf

For Zip and RAR
'zip'  =>  array('application/x-zip', 'application/zip', 'application/x-zip-compressed','application/force-download','application/octet-stream')


'rar'  =>  array('application/x-rar', 'application/rar','application/x-rar-compressed','application/force-download','application/octet-stream')
```